# Passing local variable to a partial in rails 2.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-2

I have the following method in my controller:

```
def update_fees_collection_dates_voucher
    @batch = Batch.find(params[:batch_id])
    @dates = @batch.fee_collection_dates
    render :update do |page|
        page.replace_html "fees_collection_dates", :partial =>"fees_collection_dates_voucher"
    end
end
```

the method calls the following partial in _fees_collection_dates_voucher.html.erb file:

```
<%= select  :fees_submission, :dates_id, @dates.map { |e| [e.full_name, e.id]},{:prompt => "#{t('select_fee_collection_date')}"},{:onChange => "#{remote_function( :url => {:action => "load_fees_voucher"},:with => "'date='+value+'&batch_id='+@batch.id") }"} %>
```

The partial makes a remote call to the load_fees_voucher method when a selection list value is selected or changed. However, I'm unable to pass the information in the @batch instance variable (from my original method) to the remote method via the partial. If I change the @batch.id to a hard-coded value in the last line (under :with) the code runs fine but not in the current format. Is there a different procedure to access instance variables in partials ?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same instance variable in the partials.

Try this,

```
 <%= select  :fees_submission, :dates_id, @dates.map { |e| [e.full_name, e.id]},{:prompt => "#{t('select_fee_collection_date')}"},{:onChange => "#{remote_function( :url => {:action => "load_fees_voucher"},:with => "'date='+value+'&batch_id='+#{@batch.id}") }"} %>
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks :) ... can you explain a little on how this works or point me to the relevant documentation for this ? Thanks!

Comment: from what I have understood. While evaluating a value in a string it's necessary, for example `"i am from #{place}"` here place will be evaluated to it's value.